# Why do our windows collect condensation?

Tags: windows

All of our windows vapour. They have been replaced about ~10 years ago.

From outside the house got ~10 cm dryvit. The house was built out of "grey silicon" bricks.

We have heating with Co-firing, with buffer tank.

We always heat up every room, every time.

**Question**: what could the cause of the vapouring be?

[image]

UPDATE: maybe the windows are out of argon? or never had any? how do I know?

UPDATE#2: The water is inside the house, I can touch it with my finger.

Comment: Is the water inside the window, between the panes? Or can you touch it with your finger?

Comment: I updated the question, thx

Comment: LOL. There are at least 4 things in this question that I don't understand. "Dryvit"? "Grey silicon bricks"? "Co-firing"? Bottom line, any window will collect condensation if the interior humidity is too high. It's important to vent moisture from bathrooms, etc. during cold weather. I've seen high-quality windows in fairly new homes completely rotted away due to disregard for moisture.

Comment: Dryvit is a brand of EIFS, an exterior wall covering. I'm not familiar with "grey silicon bricks" specifically but this undoubtedly refers to some type of masonry block.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, the cause is excess humidity indoors when it is cold outside. Your windows are not defective, but they are not the kind of super-high-performance windows that would be warm enough not to attract condensation. You should investigate sources of moisture indoors. Usually houses are dry in the winter, not wet, so this is a bit unusual. Do you use a humidifier? If so, turn it down.

Answer (score 1):

When the glass gets cold enough it will draw moisture from the air, just like condensation on a glass of iced water.  This doesn't imply that the windows are bad, just cold.

Modern buildings are sealed much better than old older buildings.  This is generally a good thing, but one of the problems is that it is harder to get rid of excessive humidity.

This condensation can cause problems such as mold, mildew, and/or damaged paint.

To help with this you need to reduce the humidity inside your home:

- Use exhaust fans to vent steamy air during (or after) running the shower
- Similarly, if boiling water on the stove, use a hood vent (or open a window)
- Make sure your clothes dryer's vent hose isn't leaking warm moist air into your house.
- If these aren't sufficient, buy a dehumidifier

A relatively inexpensive dehumidifier simply sits in the corner and collects water from the air. The water collects in a reservoir, which you have to empty regularly.  However, I would highly recommend installing a drain hose. It's amazing how much liquid can be gathered in just a few hours!